# How to get the data stored inside the hashmap from another class

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm pretty new to Java development and still learning, right now I'm stuck at getting the data of a HashMap from another class.

Basically I have a class that contains my hashmap, this class will only have hashmaps and list to store my data, then another class will get this hashmap and store some data to it, after that another class needs to access the hashmap to get some values that was stored to them.

So far I only know three ways to access those HashMap

1. I think by using the extend keyword to extend the hashmap class to my other class? did not try this yet
2. By using the static keyword, the one I'm using before and basically abusing the static keyword, which I'm also trying to avoid now.
3. Finally is by getting an instance of that class? which is what I'm using now and getting problems

To explain the problem, I have this data class, that will contains all my hashmaps

```
public class getLocation {
   HashMap<String, Location> location = new HashMap<>();

   public HashMap<String, Location> getloc(){
        return location;
    }
}
```

Then this is one of my class that will put some data

```
public class set1 {
   // As far as I know this will create a new instance, therefore the hashmap will be a new empty one
   private getLocation getLoc = new getLocation();

   // Putting some data
   public void setPosition() {
       getLoc.getloc().put("Position_1", Location);
   }
}
```

Then finally the third class

```
public class setBlock {
   // Again getting a new instance, therefore an empty hashmap again..
   private getLocation getLoc = new getLocation();

   public void getBlock() {
       System.out.println(getLoc.getloc().get("Position_1"));
   }
   
}
```

I think this basically just return null because I'm creating a new instance therefore it will always be empty. Is there a proper way to do this?? Before I'm just using the static keyword on every HashMap I have, but I learned that it's not a good habit therefore I'm trying to learn the proper way.

Almost all of the things I read online is just creating a hashmap, then calling it on another class and setting it's data there and that's it, what I need is to access it again on another class.

Sorry if I'm getting redundant in explaining things, just want to explain it the best I can.

If you have any suggestion on how to properly do this or something please help me

Comment: Where is Location class ?

Comment: Hey Emmanuel, I just want to let you know that there are naming conventions for classes, fields, methods, etc... and it is good practice to follow those. class names for example should be capitalized nouns.[see naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)

Comment: `setBlock` and `get1` should not create new instances of `lgetLocation` for themselves.  They should be **told** what`getLocation` instance to use.

Comment: Hey Dren sorry for the confusion, this a plugin I use and that method has a parameter player, and that location is basically just a player.getLocation(), I tried to minimize it sorry, everything works well it's just I don't know how to get those data without creating a new instance

Comment: Hey Madlemon yes that's also one of the things I trying to fix, still getting confuse about those things, but I'm getting the hang of it

Comment: Hey kevin, yes that's what I'm trying to learn now, not sure how to get this though been trying to search about getting data from another class and no luck so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you do **not** want to expose your Data-Storage (in this case your hashmap). Rather you want other Objects to interact with your HashMap in a specific way.

This is, what I think you want to achieve: Objects of this Class will store Locations for Players provide those Locations given the Player.

```
// Aside from "Start with Capital letter", the name of a Class should give
// (more than) a hint about its purpose. "getLocation" is a bad, bad, bad name
// because 1) it will not be obvious it's a class and 2) can be confused by humans
// for a method.
public class Storage {

    HashMap<Player, Location> locationStorage;

    // This is the constructor for Storage-objects.
    // It's called with the `new` keyword and creates itself 
    // a new HashMap. 
    // Each Storage-object will have its own HashMap `locationStorage`
    public Storage() {
        this.locationStorage = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    // This is a so-called Getter-Method, that exposes the HashMap
    // to other classes in a defined way; it will retrieve the Location-Object
    // associated with the `key` in the Storage's `locationStorage`.
    public Location getLocation(Player player) {
        return this.locationStorage.get(player);
    }

    // This is a so-called Setter-Method, that exposes a way to add
    // a value to our HashMap `locationStorage`
    public void setLocation(Player player, Location loc) {
        this.locationStorage.put(player, loc);
    }

}
```

Let's further assume we have a `Player` class that looks like this:

```
public class Player {

    private Location playerLocation;
    // ... other variables
    
    public Location getLocation() {
        return this.playerLocation;
    }

}
```

We could then have a class that has your `main()` method:

```
public class MainGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // using the keyword `new` we can instantiate an Object of the following class
        Storage storage = new Storage();
        // Let's assume you have a Player class that that holds a Location
        Player player = new Player();

        // Storing the Location object of the Player object in our Storage object
        storage.setLocation(player, player.getLocation());

        // retrieving the Location of the player Player
        Location currentLocation = storage.getLocation(player);
    }
}
```